# WPF Datagrid refresh and maintaining Sort Order or Scroll

Tags: .net, wpf, datatable

I have a WPF datagrid bound to my ViewModel that contains Observable property in it. Problem is that whenever i new fetch DataTable it perfectly reflects changed rows on the datagrid but i loose scroll position and SortOrder. I know solution is to keep Observable object alive and instead of assigning a new DataTable to this property i should focus on updating rows. But DataTable Rows don't implements INotifyPropertyChange and in my solution i can't use any data object other than DataTable. What should i do to fix this?

Comment: try posting your code

Comment: it is a part of solution, i would have to create some test project for that. let me try that